# How to get checkbox count value in treeview on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

> On return JSON Ajax Success we are having treeview Structure Checkbox
>   view I need to take the Checkbox count when i click the save button

```
 @model MedeilMVC_CLOUD.Models.UserView
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedDomainValue(DomainID) {
        var adminID = jQuery('[id$=hdnAdminID]').val();
        var roleID = $("#RoleID").val();
        var domainID = $("#DomainID").val();
        //$("#Doamin").remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("BindDomainUserAccess")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { RoleID: roleID, DomainID: domainID, AdminID: adminID },
            success: function (data) {
                var html = '';
                $.each(data.DomainUserViews, function (index, item) {

                    html += '<li class="dd-item"><a href="#">' + "<input type='checkbox' id='" + item.DomainID + "' name='DomainUserViews' class='DomainUserViews' />" + " " + item.DomainName + '</a>'

                    html += '<ul id="tree" class="dd-list">'

                    $.each(data.ModuleUserViews, function (index, item) {
                        if (item.ParentModuleID == -1) {

                            item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName
                        }
                        else {
                            item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName + " / " + item.Url
                        }

                        html += '<li class="dd-item"><a href="#">' + "<input type='checkbox' id='" + item.ModuleID + "' name='ModuleUserViews' class='ModuleUserViews' />" + " " + item.ModuleName + '</a></li>'

                    });

                    html += '</ul></li>'
                });

                if (html != '') {
                    html = '<ul id="tree" class="dd-list">' + html + '</ul>'
                }

                $('.dd-list').html(html);

            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="col-lg-12" id="Doamin">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="dd tree" id="nestable" style="background: #eceff4; padding: 6px;">
                <ul id="tree" class="dd-list"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On submit Button:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var ddlRole = $("#RoleID").val();
                alert("RoleID:" + ddlRole);

//Checkbox checked value code:

            });
```

When i click btnSubmit get checkbox checked Count value

Answer (score 1):

```js
var html = '';
var data = {"DomainUserViews":[{"DomainName":"a","DomainID":"a"},{"DomainName":"b","DomainID":"b"},{"DomainName":"c","DomainID":"c"}],"ModuleUserViews":[{"ModuleID":"a","Url":"a","ModuleName":"a"},{"ModuleID":"b","Url":"b","ModuleName":"b"},{"ModuleID":"c","Url":"c","ModuleName":"c"}]};
$.each(data.DomainUserViews, function (index, item) {
    html += '<li class="dd-item"><a href="#">' + "<input type='checkbox' id='" + item.DomainID + "' name='DomainUserViews' class='my_chkBox' />" + " " + item.DomainName + '</a>'
    html += '<ul id="tree" class="dd-list">'
    $.each(data.ModuleUserViews, function (index, item) {
        if (item.ParentModuleID == -1) {
            item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName
        }
        else {
            item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName + " / " + item.Url
        }

        html += '<li class="dd-item"><a href="#">' + "<input type='checkbox' id='" + item.ModuleID + "' name='ModuleUserViews' class='my_chkBox' />" + " " + item.ModuleName + '</a></li>'
     });
     html += '</ul></li>'
});

if (html != '')
{
    html = '<ul id="tree" class="dd-list">' + html + '</ul>'
}

$('.dd-list').html(html);

$("#btnSubmitDomain").click(function () {
    var ddlRole = $("#RoleID").val();
    //alert("RoleID:" + ddlRole);
    var elems = $("ul.dd-list > ul > li > a :checkbox:checked");
    var ids=[];
    elems.each(function(index){ids.push($(this).attr("id"));})
    alert("Count : "+elems.length+" IDs : "+ids);
});

$("#btnSubmitModule").click(function () {
    var ddlRole = $("#RoleID").val();
    //alert("RoleID:" + ddlRole);
    var elems = $("ul.dd-list > ul > li > ul :checkbox:checked");
    var ids=[];
    elems.each(function(index){ids.push($(this).attr("id"));})
    alert("Count : "+elems.length+" IDs : "+ids);
});

$("#btnSubmitTotalCount").click(function () {
    var ddlRole = $("#RoleID").val();
    //alert("RoleID:" + ddlRole);
    var elems = $("div#nestable :checkbox:checked");
    var ids=[];
    elems.each(function(index){ids.push($(this).attr("id"));})
    alert("Count : "+elems.length+" IDs : "+ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nestable">
  <ul class="dd-list"></ul>
</div>
<button id="btnSubmitDomain">Get DomainUserViews Count</button>
<button id="btnSubmitModule">Get ModuleUserViews Count</button>
<button id="btnSubmitTotalCount">Get ModuleUserViews Count</button>
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for. The following gets the count of `checked` checkboxes. If this is not what you are looking for, just leave a comment. :)

```
$("div#nestable :checkbox:checked").length;
```

**Edit:** Updated a code snippet it alerts the count, on clicking the button. I have used a dummy data to populate the html.

Comment: in json return value we are sending two objects one is `DomainUserViews` another one is `ModuleUserViews` in your code get full count but i need separate value For Example  `DomainUserViews` how many checkbox clicked and get id value any idea?

Comment: any idea @Vignesh Raja

Comment: See my comments @Vignesh Raja

Comment: I am still updating it. Pls wait.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162795/discussion-between-vignesh-raja-and-ivin-raj).

Comment: Pls join the above chat. Its easy to discuss everything in chat instead of comments :)

Comment: Wait a minutes sir

Answer (score 1):

Build a simple count function that gets all checkboxes, filters them to only the ones that are checked and then count the total. Example below with `jQuery.length`.

**Edit**: If you want to count discreet sets of checkboxes, say from `DomainUserViews` vs `ModuleUserViews`, put different classes on those `<ul>` elements (instead of just `.dd-list` alone) and change `.dd-list` in the snippet below to the class you're targeting.

**Edit 2**: Updated code example to match the classes in your updated question.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function countDomains(){
    var $checked = $('.DomainUserViews:checked');
    var out = "There are " + $checked.length + " domains checked";
    $('.totalDomains').html(out);
  }
  
  function countModules(){
    var $checked = $('.ModuleUserViews:checked');
    var out = "There are " + $checked.length + " modules checked";
    $('.totalModules').html(out);
  }

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    countDomains();
    countModules();
  });
  $("#btnSubmitDomains").click(function () {
    countDomains();
  });
    $("#btnSubmitModules").click(function () {
    countModules();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tree" class="dd-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="DomainUserViews" checked> Domain 1
    <ul class="dd-list">
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews" checked>Module 1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews" checked>Module 2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews">Module 3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews" checked>Module 4</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews">Module 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="DomainUserViews" checked> Domain 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="DomainUserViews"> Domain 3
    <ul class="dd-list">
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews" checked>Module 1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews" checked>Module 2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews">Module 3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews" checked>Module 4</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="ModuleUserViews">Module 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="DomainUserViews" checked> Domain 4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="DomainUserViews"> Domain 5</li>
</ul>  
<button id="btnSubmitDomains">Count domains</button>
<button id="btnSubmitModules">Count modules</button>
<button id="btnSubmit">Count Both</button>
<p class="totalDomains"></p>
<p class="totalModules"></p>
```

Comment: in json return value we are sending two objects one is DomainUserViews another one is ModuleUserViews in your code get full count but i need separate value For Example DomainUserViews how many checkbox clicked and get id value any idea?

Comment: @IvinRaj Updated the answer with an explanation of how to get discreet counts.

Comment: am new in this technology can you update my code please

Comment: @IvinRaj Updated again to match your new class names. I can only mock the nested listed structure but hopefully that explains it.